# SQLite query no longer works in Android 5.0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

I have added some additional search functionality to my app - tested and works fine on Android 4.4.2.

Have just updated my device to 5.0 and this new search functionality doesn't work, returning an empty cursor. (The other queries in the app all work fine on all devices, indicating that this is a code issue rather than a data issue.)

I understand that, from Android 4.4.2 to Android 5.0, SQLite was updated from 3.7.11 to 3.8.0, which I expect is the reason for this issue. I've looked at the [changelog for SQLite 3.8.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_0.html) and there is nothing that stands out as being of obvious concern (to my untrained eye, anyway).

Here is the query in question that is produced by my code:

```
SELECT
    statuses.status AS status,
    shelves.shelf_name AS shelf_name, 
    aisles.aisle_name AS aisle_name, 
    products.image_file_name_stored AS image_file_name_stored, 
    parent_companies.url AS url, 
    parent_companies.email AS email, 
    products.buy_url AS buy_url, 
    products_data.status_id AS status_id, 
    parent_companies.company_name AS company_name, 
    products.image_file_name AS image_file_name, 
    '(' || shelves.shelf_name || ')' AS suggest_text_2, 
    products._id AS suggest_intent_data_id, 
    products.product_name AS suggest_text_1, 
    parent_companies.tel AS tel, 
    products.product_name AS product_name, 
    products_data.notes AS notes, 
    products.priority AS priority, 
    products._id AS _id, 
    products_data.last_modified_on AS last_modified_on 

FROM 
    products

INNER JOIN 
    parent_companies ON products.parent_company_id = parent_companies._id

INNER JOIN 
    shelves ON products.shelf_id = shelves._id

INNER JOIN
    aisles ON shelves.aisle_id = aisles._id

INNER JOIN 
    products_data ON products._id = products_data.product_id

INNER JOIN
    statuses ON products_data.status_id = statuses._id

WHERE 
    (shelves._id = ?)

ORDER BY
    shelf_name ASC
```

And my `selectionArgs = {"156"}`.

**UPDATE**

Now, just to test, I've set the `selection` String to `null` and the `selectionArgs` String[] to `null` and the **cursor is now full of results** - too many, of course as there is no longer a `WHERE` condition.

So, my question is ultimately this... Why does having the following selection criteron gives results in Android 4.4.2 (SQLite 3.7.11) but no results in Android 5.0 (SQLite 3.8.0) ?...

```
String selection = "shelves._id = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"156"};
```

...surely it's not that I am trying to compare an **integer** column (`_id`) with a **String** (`"156"`) ?!

**UPDATE #2**

Using the problematic query, I've stepped in with debugger and, on line 393 of SQLiteQueryBuilder.java, then sql String is...

> "SELECT statuses.status AS status, shelves.shelf_name AS shelf_name,
>   aisles.aisle_name AS aisle_name, products.image_file_name_stored AS
>   image_file_name_stored, parent_companies.url AS url,
>   parent_companies.email AS email, products.buy_url AS buy_url,
>   products_data.status_id AS status_id, parent_companies.company_name AS
>   company_name, products.image_file_name AS image_file_name, '(' ||
>   shelves.shelf_name || ')' AS suggest_text_2, products._id AS
>   suggest_intent_data_id, products.product_name AS suggest_text_1,
>   parent_companies.tel AS tel, products.product_name AS product_name,
>   products_data.notes AS notes, products.priority AS priority,
>   products._id AS _id, products_data.last_modified_on AS
>   last_modified_on FROM products INNER JOIN parent_companies ON
>   products.parent_company_id = parent_companies._id INNER JOIN shelves
>   ON products.shelf_id = shelves._id INNER JOIN aisles ON
>   shelves.aisle_id = aisles._id INNER JOIN products_data ON products._id
>   = products_data._id INNER JOIN statuses ON products_data.status_id = statuses._id WHERE (shelves._id = ?) ORDER BY shelf_name ASC"

...which looks fine. I continued to step through with the debugger to see where it goes wrong, but when I stepped into the `db.rawQueryWithFactory()` method, the debugger seemed to get lost (it took me to a comment line), so I'm not sure what the actual issue could have been.

Comment: "the cursor is now full of results" -- but is the one with a `shelves._id` of 156 among them? If not, then it's a data problem.

Comment: There is no reason for the query as written to work on 4.4.2 but not on 5.0. Either you have a data problem or the code which queries the database has some problem.

Comment: See my answer, below. Maybe I have discovered a bug. My data and code is fine. The only thing that makes the above query different from the other query in my app that works fine on Android 4.4.2 and Android 5.0 is the `selection` / `selectionArgs` values.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the `(parentheses)` from the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Thanks, Graham, but the parentheses are added by Android. I'm just using `String selection = "shelves._id = ?";`.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion was correct. I have just tried this code to modify `selection` and `selectionArgs` and everything now works as expected:

```
        if (selection != null && selectionArgs != null && selectionArgs.length == 1 && isNumeric(selectionArgs[0])) {
            selection = selection.replace("?", selectionArgs[0]); // e.g., changes "shelves._id = ?" to "shelves._id = 156"
            selectionArgs = null; // e.g., changes {"156"} to null
        }
```